# UML child parent relationship

Tags: class, uml, parent-child, relationship, diagram

I have a class named car and it is a child class of vehicle. 
Now I want to create an UML class diagram of car without having to draw vehicle and pointing a derivation arrow to it. 
I want all the derivation information directly in the car class diagram.

Does a notation for that purpose exist in UML?

Best regards,

Cookie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is not possible to indicate that `Car` inherits from `Vehicle` while not drawing `Vehicle`, but note that you can omit the information that is not relevant. In this case, since you are modelling `Car`, you may **omit the attributes and operation compartments** of `Vehicle`, like this:

[image]

The UML specification gives the following guideline: "*show full attributes and operations when needed and suppress them in other contexts or when merely referring to a class* and says that "*any compartment may be suppressed. A separator line is not drawn for a suppressed compartment. If a compartment is suppressed, no inference can be drawn about the presence or absence of elements in it.*"
(UML Superstructure Specification, v2.4.1; pag 50 and 54).

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to represent this is a generalization link.
But depending of your tool, you may have this kind of information inside another window...

Answer (score -1):

Draw two diagrams, on the first one draw generalization relationship between classes and on the second one draw classes only to design your models.